# Qt parent widget could't be updated

Tags: qt, opengl

I'm writing a tetris game in qt/opengl.

The game is partially event-driven (Game class, which is a QGLWidget), and the other part is in a QThread (GameLogic class). My problem occured when I tried to put this widget inside a parent widget among with a 'menu' widget. Even if I send signals from the game-widgets paintGL() method to the parent widget in order to refresh itself (the parent), nothing happens, and my app looks like it's frozen.

Although when I try resize() instead of repaint(), the parent widget resizes (and i guess also refreshes) itself and we can see how far the game had come.

So basically my game-widget and the thread works fine, but i didn't manage to ask the parent widget to simply update itself (if it's the problem). I've tried update(), repaint(), both of them with `QCoreApplication::processEvents()`, and connecting with QueuedConnection and DirectConnection as well. I've got a bunch of 'recursive repaint' error messages, although the parent didn't seem to be updated.

Comment: Could you split your question in paragraphs? It's difficult to read right now.

Comment: Did you call exec on your main application object? That's where the events get processed

Comment: Yes, i did.
Turned out, the thread must be started from the main widget - guess it's a newbie mistake. Sorry about that, and thank you for the help!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.